# Why can't I enter the code? mui tag conditional

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, classname

Why can't I use boolean?

I want to check whether I am an admin or not.
and hide the button or disable the button

```
 const Authenticate = useSelector(userSelector)
  let check :boolean = true;

<Link href="/stock" passHref className={Authenticate.level != 'admin' ? check=false:check=true}> // className redline
          <ListItem
            button
            className={router.pathname === "/stock" ? "Mui-selected" : ""}
            disabled={check}
          >
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Layers />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Stock" />
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but there might be a typo...you can try `let check: boolean;` then
`check = true;`

Comment: I have tried changing it and it's the same.

Comment: is 'check' is the class name?

Comment: is `check` and  `disabled={check}` ,  `true` or `false`  in `<ListItem>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it after I put

```
disabled={Authenticate.level == 'admin' ? false:true}
```

in `<ListItem>`

thank everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Link href="/stock" passHref className={Authenticate.level != 'admin' ? 'className1' : 'className2'}> </Link>
```

Comment: How can I disable `<ListItem>` if `className1` and `className2` is `string`?